# How to connect azure devops and bitbucket using 2 step verification

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I currently have bitbucket cloud connected to azure-devops using OAuth authentication as described in the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

I want to enable 2 step verification on BitBucket - https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/enable-two-step-verification/

Can someone please let me know what changes are required on Azure Devops to enable it to connect to bitbucket using 2 step verification and how will I go about getting this setup

Any help appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to connect azure devops and bitbucket using 2 step verification

As we know, enable two-step verification will improve protection of user accounts. However, enabling two-step verification (2SV) complicates cloning, pulling and pushing to repositories of the account, if they are accessed over HTTPs.

So, if we use SSH to access the repositories, nothing changes after enabling two-step verification.

If you use HTTPs access, after 2SV is enabled you will need to configure an Access token (BitBucket calls it [app password](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/)) and use it to authenticate. When prompted for credentials, either enter token as username and leave the password field empty or use the token instead of your password.

> App passwords are substitute passwords for a user account which you
> can use for scripts and integrating tools to avoid putting your real
> password into configuration files.
>
> App passwords are designed to be used for a single purpose with
> limited permissions, **so they don't require two-step verification
> (2SV)**. This means app passwords can be used by users with 2SV make API
> calls to their Bitbucket account, and to integrate Bitbucket with
> other tools like Sourcetree and Bamboo.